# UK resident working overseas. Planning a 2 week vacation. For purposes of travel insurance, how long is my "trip"?

Tags: regulations, insurance

I've been living and working in China for a year now. I think I am still classed as a 'UK resident' (since I intend to return). I am about to go on a 2 week holiday to India. I've noticed that most travel insurance policies (at least, the cheap ones) specify a 'maximum trip length', typically 21-31 days.

This led me to wonder, for the purposes of insurance, how long is my trip?

I found this article:
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/expat/health/travel-insurance-for-brits-abroad-do-you-have-the-right-kind-of/

Which says:

*"For a UK policy to be valid, you need to be resident in the UK, have an address in the UK and would need to be going on a pre-booked trip that starts and finishes in the UK"*

I'm a little confused... does this mean I need a China-based policy? If I book a UK one I risk not being covered?

From the perspective of a UK based insurer, is this all one big 400+ day trip?
How does this work...?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: After a year China will consider you a resident for tax purposes and the UK won't. If your trip starts and finishes in China I'd guess UK insurers will also consider you a China resident. What you 'intend' to do doesn't matter since you may not do it for a long time, or ever. This really looks like a question for [Expatriates.se]

Comment: Thanks, I just cross-posted it there. I have actually been living here for just under a year, but some of the paperwork, such as when I applied for a visa, will be just over a year, which makes it a bit ambiguous... I have a Chinese residence permit, so perhaps I would be safer with Chinese insurance.

Comment: "I think I still am a UK reaident since I intend to return." Errr no. You're a [temporary] resident in China. What you intend to do in the future has no bearing on your current situation. You say you have a Chinese residence permit, thus you answered your own question...

Comment: I think this is not an expats questions since the core issue (Is my insurance valid for *this travel?)* is a travel one.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you almost certainly need another policy.**

First the insurance makes it clear that your trip has to start and end in the UK, which, if you are talking about your vacation, it doesn't. That's absolutely normal in travel insurance. If you wanted to have the insurer consider this "one big 400 day+ trip" you would have to buy insurance for the whole 400+ days (which would fall under a completely different category from vacation travel insurance).

Second, you are probably not a UK resident. [You are not a UK resident (for tax purposes) if you work full time overseas and spend less than 91 days in the UK during the year.](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/547118/160803_RDR3_August2016_v2_0final_078500.pdf) If you aren't paying taxes to the UK then you are almost certainly not a UK resident.

If you are thinking about health coverage, your first step should be to look at whatever health coverage you already have to cover your time in China. You might find it already covers trips abroad. If not you are definitely going to need either a policy based in China or a worldwide policy that doesn't assume UK residence.